# Ember-Drag-Sort: Custom HTML element

Tags: ember.js, ember-drag-sort

is it possible to specify a custom element tag for the .dragList ? In my scenario right now I need it to be a `<ul>` as I'm rendering my items wrapped inside of `<li>` - trying to avoid having to create a fork.

something like this...

```
    = drag-sort-list [
      tagName="ul"
      childTagName="li"
      class="someClass"
    ]
```

and instead of default rendering a  for the list we could render the tagName passed in - would also be nice to be able to pass down a custom class for the parent list as well

Comment: In your future questions, please convert your code to vanilla JS and Handlebars, so that your question is understandable to other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure tag names of both `drag-sort-list` and `drag-sort-item` components:

```
{{#drag-sort-list
  tagName      = "article"
  childTagName = "section"
}}
```

`tagName` is built into every Ember component.

`childTagName` is described in the addon's [readme](https://github.com/Deveo/ember-drag-sort#drag-sort-list-arguments-reference).